# What is the maximum addressable RAM for a process in Linux on 2P Opteron

Tags: linux, memory, opteron

I'm doing some bioinformatics work where the limitation is amount of memory (i.e., the process is not parallelizable). I see servers like the Dell R715 that have two sockets for Opteron 6100 CPUs and 128GB of RAM possible with 16 x 8GB DIMMs.

Each CPU has a bank of DIMMs associated with it.

My question is, if I put Linux on a machine like that, is only half the RAM addressable by each CPU? In other words, if I run a single-threaded program under Linux will that process have access to 128GB of RAM or only 64GB of RAM?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strictly speaking, that single-threaded process will have access to all memory available to the server. You don't have to worry about that.

The process will have access to *all* memory in RAM, but access to half of it will be (in theory) slower than access to the other half of it. I know VMWare-ESX is aware of memory locality, as it attempts to keep all the memory for a specific VM on the same memory node as the process execution in order to keep performance good.

The technology is called Non-Uniform Memory Access (NUMA). Chances are your Linux machine already has the bits for it (`numastat` should return data). The `numactl` program assigns a memory policy to your processes, which can be very useful if you're writing your own code and want to optimize for memory speed. CPU-local memory will fetch faster than memory in another CPU's memory node, which may be useful for you depending on what you're doing with it.

Answer (score 0):

Linux is a demand paged system that presents a virtual address space of 2^64 -1 on a 64 bit system.  the VMM wil lhave access all of the ram in the box.  The linux kernel handles creating the page table not the process.